# 勉強に行きます or 勉強しに行きます?

Tags: grammar

I am on みんなの日本語１chapter 13 and there is a sentence: 日本へ美術の勉強に行きました。According to their explanation, the phrase after へ can be either be a noun or a verbます-form so using 勉強します instead, is 日本へ美術を勉強しに行きました correct? If it is wrong, what is the correct way of writing it?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70384/9831 ... and maaybe this one too? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5134/9831

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn’t find these threads at all.